# What does this "neither....nor" sentence really mean?

Tags: grammaticality

> "There are neither serious doubts about Facebook’s dominant position on the German social network market nor the fact that Facebook is abusing this dominant position,” the court said.

What does the above sentence mean? Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: I think it means: "There are neither serious doubts....nor are there doubts that ...."   One thing is certain:  There are no doubts that the sentence is a mess.

Comment: @ab2; Please put this in an answer and be done with it.

Comment: @Elliot What I wrote isn't answer-quality.  It is merely comment-quality.  If you want to write an answer based on my comment, feel free.  :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of "neither . . . nor" versus "not . . . or"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10049/usage-of-neither-nor-versus-not-or)

Comment: Look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39040/neither-nor-vs-nor-neither

Comment: In my opinion, _neither_ is in the wrong place. There are doubts about _neither_ Facebook's dominant position... _nor_ the fact that...

Comment: @KateBunting I think the sentence ends up being confusing either way. There's just too much distance between "neither" and "nor", so it's easy to lose the context of what is being negated. The sentence should be reworded, IMHO.

Comment: Also, since "doubt" is a negative word, this ends up being a confusing double negative.